# Wait for API call data before render react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I make an API call.

It appears React goes ahead to build a table without the data, thus throwing error of

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Here's what I'm doing

`useEffect()` pretty straightforward

```
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const [isBusy, setBusy] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    setBusy(true);
    async function fetchData() {
      const url = `${
        process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE
        }/api/v1/endpoint/`;

      axios.get(url).then((response: any) => {
        setBusy(false);
        setData(response.data.results)
        console.log(response.data.results);
      });
    }

    fetchData();
  }, [])
```

Then I'm trying to render a table using the data from the API call above (as and when it becomes available)

```
            <div className="col-md-12 mt-5">
              {isBusy ? (
                <Loader />
              ) : (
                  <table className="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Pharmacy User Full Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Tests This Month</th>
                        <th scope="col">Tests This Week</th>
                        <th scope="col">Last Test Date</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      {data.map((item: any, index: any) => {
                        return (<tr>
                          <th scope="row" key={index}>{item.name}</th>
                          <td>Mark</td>
                          <td>Otto</td>
                          <td>@mdo</td>
                        </tr>
                        )
                      })}

                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                )}
            </div>
```

The above appears intuitive enough for me. So not sure what I need to do. Thanks.

Comment: What is your console.log showing?

Comment: @Konstantin `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Comment: I think @Vencovsky solution should work for you. Remember that you might need to parse the results received first with ```.json()```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should set `isBusy` to true in the `useState` initial value

```
//                            initial value
const [isBusy, setBusy] = useState(true)
```

And also check `data` before `data.map`

```
// checking data
{data && data.map((item: any, index: any) => {
    return (<tr>
      <th scope="row" key={index}>{item.name}</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    )
})}
```

Comment: Combining both now. The checking data part too very important. Thanks for pointing that out too. Will keep in mind

Comment: @Vencovsky - Can you pls explain why Do we check for data before data.map? Is it to make sure if data is present or not?

Comment: @lAaravl is because `data` could be `undefined` and if you do `data.map` without checking if data is truthy, you might get an error saying `cannot read property map of undefined. You also might ask "How will data be undefined?" and the reason why it can be undefined is that the `data` state is initialized as `undefined` in `const [isBusy, setBusy] = useState()` (empty parameter in `useState` is passing `undefined` as the initial state.

Comment: @lAaravl a much better check would be `Array.isArray(data) && data.map(...)` so it would only work if `data` is actually an array, but in this case, only doing `data && data.map(...)` will work also.

Answer (score 3):

`useEffect` will only set `isBusy` to `true` after the component tries to render(too late). Remember that `useEffect` only runs after the browser finishes painting. So the first assertion of `isBusy` is `undefined` which evaluates to `false`

Define `true` as initial state of `isBusy`

```
const [isBusy, setBusy] = useState(true)
```

Or check for the existence of `data` instead of `isBusy`

Comment: What if we're not using `useState` but instead `useEffect` and waiting for an API call to finish before rendering?

Answer (score 2):

Your `setBusy(true);` happens inside the `useEffect`. The `useEffect` will execute after your first render so this is too late.

I recommend setting `isBusy` to true by default via the parameter of `useState`:

```
const [isBusy, setBusy] = useState(true);
```

You then don't need to set it to true inside the `useEffect` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `isBusy` state variable entirely as it just replicates data. Unless you later decide to do something fancy like 'load more data', then I think it just complicates things.

```
<div className="col-md-12 mt-5">
  {!data? (
    <Loader />
  ) : (
     <table className="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Pharmacy User Full Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Tests This Month</th>
            <th scope="col">Tests This Week</th>
            <th scope="col">Last Test Date</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.map((item: any, index: any) => {
            return (<tr>
             <th scope="row" key={index}>{item.name}</th>
              <td>Mark</td>
              <td>Otto</td>
              <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
           )
          })}
       </tbody>
     </table>
   )}
</div>
```

In the above, if there is no data `!data` then it will show the loader. Once data gets populated it will render your table with the loaded data.

Hope this helps.